# Merging multiple csv files using python - resulting csv pushes certain data to the right in the merged csv

Tags: python, csv, merge

This is my first post so apologies for being a newb. I tried searching for the solution here and of course google.

I am trying to merge multiple csv files with the same columns and number of columns in each file into one csv file. Unfortunately the data from each subsequent csv file gets added into new columns in the merged csv file. The second column in the first image are times and have the same values in every csv.

[data from two csvs in the merged csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC5IS.png)

Also in the first row of the merged csv file, it seems to add the first row's data in every csv.

[first row has data from every csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBYOF.png)

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("/Users/ericchen/downloads/spy/")

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]


combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your csv does not have headers, so it interprets the first row as the header row, with predictable consequences. So, setting `header=None` in your `read_csv` should do the trick.